# How do I add a superclass to two classes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails application I have two classes :

`UserPost` and `GroupPost` (inheriting from ApplicationRecord), that I want to make subclasses of a new class, Post.

What would be the best way to add this in?

Is it as simple as making the class manually, and adding in the inheritance or are there problems that could cause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm making the assumption that UserPost and GroupPost are inherited from ActiveRecord::Base, i.e. you want to save them in your DB

If you have class UserPost and GroupPost inherit from Post in the following way, this is known as Single Table Inheritance

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
end

class GroupPost < Post
end

class UserPost < Post
end
```

Rails will, by default, expect you to have a column called "type" (can be configured to any other name) in the Posts table. GroupPost and UserPost will populate their respective values in the same table, adding in "GroupPost" or "UserPost" to the type. You can read up on it [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#single-table-inheritance-sti)

Rails also provides you the ability to have the parent class be "abstract", i.e. it shouldn't be able to persist to the database. Perhaps you noticed it in the the app/models/application_record.rb file as well. This way the parent serves as just a concept where you can add in common behaviour, STI will not kick in. There will need to be separate tables for children.

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

If you plan on having separate tables for the classes, I'd recommend trying composition instead of inheritance using mixins. Basically you write common functionality in a "module" and include it to the classes that need the separate functionality. Concerns are a nice way to append class methods, associations etc without having to rely on arcane ruby syntax. I'd recommend having a look at the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html)

```
module Fooable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do |base|
     scope :enabled, -> { where(enabled: true) }
     has_many :boos, dependent: :destroy
  end

  class_methods do
    def having_name
      where('name ILIKE ?', "#{name}%")
    end
  end
  
  def hi
    return 'hi'
  end
end

class UserPost < ApplicationRecord
  include Fooable
end

UserPost.first.boos # relationship
UserPost.enabled # calling a scope
UserPost.having_name('name') # calling a class method
UserPost.new.hi #calling an instance method
```